# How to make a snippet printf with \n in C (with vscode)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have a question, how to make a snippet in vscode so when you type `pr` and it will develop a code like this `printf("type here\n");` I tried this :

```
    "prefix" : "pr",
    "body": ["printf(\"$1 \n \",$2)"]
},
```

But the output will be :

```
printf(" 
 ",)
```

Comment: Escape the backslash, as in `\\n`?

Comment: For C99: `#define pr(a, ...) printf(a "\n", __VA_ARGS__)` .... see https://ideone.com/lX4ST1

Comment: @pmg, nice usage of preprocessor string concatenation, but there are some edge case failures: https://ideone.com/7w2RUo

Comment: @pmg preprocessor macros are not really in the scope of the question. OP is asking about VSCode specifically.

Comment: So @MarcoBonelli, is the C tag misused?

Comment: Good catch, @LegendofPedro. Also the macro name should be in all caps :)

Comment: @pmg well... it's most probably unneeded, yes. The issue isn't C-specific.

Comment: For my cpp usage, `"std::cout << $0 << '\\n';"`

Answer (score 0):

Just add this template in your snippet

```
"printf ending with \n":{
    "prefix": "p_e",
    "body": [
        "printf(\"$1\\n\"); "
    ]
}
```

**Note:** Here it will bring the current position where `$1` is written. If you want to change the cursor(in case if you only want to write `printf("\n");` Thus you can remove `$1` from the above snippet and it will be working fine.

Comment: Please don't add your personal contact information to answers; that's not allowed by this site's policy. You can add that information to your profile page if you want.